# Nifi InvokeHTTP Not Honoring Configured Trust Store

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm really confused with **NiFi InvokeHTTP** processor - it's simply not honoring trust store configured in the mapped **StandardSSLContextService**. The trust store (Java cacerts file) contains self-signed certificate imported.
I know what I'm doing, checked multiple tutorials.

Could anyone suggest, is it a known issue with NiFi specifically with this processor?
Because Java client honors trust store and works without any issues. GetHTTP processor in NiFi works also and honors the trust store.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you create your truststore file with your cacerts? You should create truststore with java keytool. please check this article. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html

Comment: Yes I did and configured it in StandardSSLContextService.

Comment: Also, This trusstore is already used by other Java clients without any issues.
Also, GetHTTP and PostHTTP processors in Nifi work - only the issues with InvokeHTTP one.